# Installation of virtual-box on Netscalar FreeBSD instance

Tags: virtualbox, freebsd, amazon-ec2, citrix, freebsd-ports

We have one Netscalar instance having platinum AMI: NetScaler ADC VPX Platinum Edition - 10 Mbps. As a part of infrastructure management we want to install VirtualBox on this FreeBSD Netscaler instance. But as I can see , there are no ports and packages installed in this AMI and so it prevents me to proceed with the virtualbox installation. Either I have to install ports and packages somehow on this instance or directly virtualbox if possible. I am following below procedure for this installation:

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/virtualization-host-virtualbox.html

Please guide me if this is possible in the first place and how we should proceed with the same requirement?